# App Launch: The Huawei Lite Simulator supports only Lite projects

Tags: huawei-developers, harmonyos, deveco-studio

When trying to run my test app on a HVD emulator, I get the following error message:

```
App Launch: The Huawei Lite Simulator supports only Lite projects.
```

Meanwhile [I've realized](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/run_simulator-0000001053303709), that currently one can only use hardware or a remote emulator for such a project. But when trying to set this up, the Harmony OS Virtual Device Manager responds with 404:

[image]

Is there anything to do about it?

Comment: Hi Martin, Your Login session has expired, so you are getting 404. Please restart browser and retry login from DevEco. I too faced similar error, but I'm able to connect remote Simulator. I'm using DevEco version 2.1.0.501.

Comment: @GowthamGS Well, it happened immediately after (likely an oAuth2) login - and 404 isn't 401. And I find DevEco difficult to adopt, because cannot load the IDEA plugin on Linux. Will have to return the hardware today (which I've actually liked), since the form where to register for EMM is also broken. I've just tried again; I don't know which URL the HVD manager is requesting, but it's a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried with DevEco Studio on Windows so far, but with Android Studio on Linux, which appears to be functioning now.

With HMS Toolkit version `1.0.5`, it will ask for Huawei ID and then also lists devices in Düsseldorf or Ireland (where the one is a city and the other a country). However, there are currently only EMUI ROM available. It integrates better than before, but without an HarmonyOS 2.0 ROM, it still doesn't provide the expected environment.